# How to use route variable immediately after define in angular 11?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular11, routeparams, route-parameters

I want to use route variable for breadcrumb title. For example:

```
{
 path:'sample/:title',
 data:{
 breadcrumb:[
   {title:'sample',link:'sample'},
   {title:using :title variable here}
   ]
 }
}
```

Is there a way to use variable immediately after define?

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following :

```
constructor(private router: Router  ) {}

 this.router.navigate(['/page', { data: YourData'}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If the title is fixed a good place to keep breadcrumb data in route config.

   ```
   {
         path:'sample',
         data:{
          breadcrumb:"sample"
         }
    }
   ```
2. If the title is variable you can use this.

```
   constructor(private router: Router  ) {}
   .....
   .....
   goTo() {this.router.navigate(['/page', { data:  YourData'}]);}
```

But this is not a good approach from my end. I always need to set data where I need a  breadcrumb. I think we should make a component where we format the full breadcrumb from the URL and apply it to the view. After that, we use that sharable component to our main components.

Comment: Where ever you make the breadcrumb component, needs to get the route data. I'm looking for a way to use route variable immediately after define.